# Any Ideas how to iterate an element in the each loop in jQuery from within a click function within it?

Tags: jquery, this, children, each

I have a `click` function inside an `each` loop in jQuery, I need to iterate the element of the `each` loop from within the `click` function, anyone has an Idea how? I know that `$(this)` in the scenario below will result in the element of the `click()` Is there any way i can iterate the element in the `each` loop. Basically i want to get `.innocentGrandChild` for each of the `innocentParent`.

here is a sample of how my code looks like:

```
    $(".innocentParent").each(function(){
   $(".thumbnail").click(function(){
  ///HERE IS MY PROBLEM $(this) should be the element of the 'each' loop: '.innocentParent'
    $(this).find(".innocentGrandChild").hide();

    });
});

<div class="innocentParent">
    <div class="problemChild">
         <div class="innocentGrandChild">

        </div>
    </div>

 <div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail">1</div>
   <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
   <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
  </div>

</div>

 <div class="innocentParent">
    <div class="problemChild">
         <div class="innocentGrandChild">

        </div>
    </div>

<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail">1</div>
   <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
   <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
  </div>


</div>

 <div class="innocentParent">
    <div class="problemChild">
         <div class="innocentGrandChild">

        </div>
    </div>

<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail">1</div>
   <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
   <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Sorry guys I forgot to ADD 1 important factor, I am actually clicking 1 of the group of the elements outside of the `.innocentParent` This is where Im having the problem, lets ignore the actual function of the script, Im only having trouble with iterating to the right child element for each of the `innocentParent`

Explaination: on click of each of the thumbnails within the each container "innocentParent" I need to hide the right "innocentGrandChild" - sorry for any mis directions

Comment: This is so wrong,

You are binding all problemChild elements on screen one click function for all innocentPeople on the screen. What are you trying to achieve? You want it to hide innocentGrandChild on click of problemChild?

Comment: Having seen your new HTML, I have to ask if you can explain the *intended* behavior more clearly? e.g. What `.innocentGrandChild` do you want hidden if thumbnail #1 is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obvious from the code what the intended behavior is, but I am guessing you may want to hide the matching innocentGrandChild, based on the ordinal position (index) of the thumbnail clicked.

If so try this way:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.innocentParent').eq(index).find(".innocentGrandChild").hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bp77dxgm/2/

*if this is not the intended behavior, please explain it in more detail.*

Comment: This will work fine bro, but I had already used .parent() and then find the correct "innocentGrandChild" from there, my HTML needed editing and sorry for that but your solution will still work just by giving it a glance, havent tried it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be that complex:

```
$('.innocentParent .problemChild').click(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.innocentGrandChild').hide();
  }
);
```

```js
$('.innocentParent .problemChild').click(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.innocentGrandChild').hide();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="innocentParent">
    <div class="problemChild">
         <div class="innocentGrandChild">
1 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="innocentParent">
    <div class="problemChild">
         <div class="innocentGrandChild">
2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="innocentParent">
    <div class="problemChild">
         <div class="innocentGrandChild">
3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Paul yes this would be simple if all my element were within the same parent element, thanks!

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with them all being in the same parent. Notice, in the example, that they are *not*.